# Could Debezium Embedded Engine get Transanction Metadata?

Tags: debezium, cdc

because we use solace as message broker, I'm studying to use debezium embedded engine for Mysql CDC.

In some scenarios, [transaction metadata](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/mysql.html#mysql-transaction-metadata) is necessary, I referred to a embedded engine sample:

```
        this.debeziumEngine = DebeziumEngine.create(ChangeEventFormat.of(Connect.class))
            .using(customerConnectorConfiguration.asProperties())
            .notifying(this::handleChangeEvent)
            .build();

...

    private void handleChangeEvent(RecordChangeEvent<SourceRecord> sourceRecordRecordChangeEvent) {
        SourceRecord sourceRecord = sourceRecordRecordChangeEvent.record();
...
}
```

with gtid_mode=ON, I can get gtid in the value of sourceRecord, but have no idea how to listen the transaction event.

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO customerdb.customer (id, fullname, email) VALUES (19, 'gee', 'gee@example.com');
COMMIT;
```

by running above script, seems the engine cannot get transaction begin/end event?

Could anyone enlighten me or provide some sample? Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

Solace has developed a Debezium connector to capture all the database transactions and make it available as an event in the Solace event broker.

Solace Debezium Connector is positioned as an open-source solution and we are happy to share the working solution for you to explore and position in your use case.

Please share your official email id, will share all the details.

Regards,

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).